# PL/SQL : "ORA-01008: not all variables bound"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I tried to run and execute the following block :

```
declare 
    sql_query varchar2(100);
    i number;
begin
select script into sql_query from formula_script where id = 1;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
            'select ' || sql_query || ' from dual' into i; 
end;
```

**sql_query  is a cell with varchar2 datatype with this value : '1 - 1 * &c'**

but couldn't get the result and it had the following error :

```
Error report -
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at line 6
01008. 00000 -  "not all variables bound"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

and when I run the following code, It hasn't any error:

```
select 2*4 + &c from dual;
```

thank you for your helping!

Comment: What is the value of `sql_query`? `'2*4 + &c'`, or `'2*4 + :c'`, or something else? The error implies it probably has a bind variable, so your `execute immediate` would need to supply a value for that, with `using`. But it would really help to see what you're actually executing.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I updated the question. yes it's like your example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitution is performed by the client tool (SQL*Plus, SQL Developer etc) before sending the block to the database for processing, so you need to include a substitution variable explicitly.

Also, the `&c` in the generated expression is **not a substitution variable** but a bind variable (usually written as `:c`). I must admit I was surprised that the compiler treated it as one, because normally bind variables are prefixed with `:`, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation about it, but it seems to treat `&` the same as `:`.

Finally, bind variables in dynamic SQL are positional and not named, so `&c` in the dynamic string is unrelated to any substitution variable with the same name in the script, and `:b` would have the same meaning (and perhaps be less confusing).

```
declare
    sql_query varchar2(100);
    i  number;
begin
    select script into sql_query from formula_script where id = 1;

    execute immediate 'select '||sql_query||' from dual'
        into i
        using &input_number;

    dbms_output.put_line('Expression: '||sql_query);
    dbms_output.put_line('Result: '|| i);
end;
/

Enter value for input_number: 123
Expression: 1 - 1 * &c
Result: -122
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use:

```sql
DECLARE
  sql_query varchar2(100) := '2*4 + &c';
  i number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || sql_query || ' from dual' INTO i; 
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
END;
/
```

Then your query is:

```sql
select 2*4 + &c from dual
```

And `&c` is a substitution variable. However, when you use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` without a `USING` clause then there is no input to specify the value of the substitution variable so it will be unbound and you will get the error:

```
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-06512: at line 5
```

From the [`EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/EXECUTE-IMMEDIATE-statement.html#GUID-C3245A95-B85B-4280-A01F-12307B108DC8):

> #### bind_argument
>
> An expression whose value replaces its corresponding placeholder in  `dynamic_sql_stmt` at run time.
>
> Every placeholder in `dynamic_sql_stmt` must be associated with a `bind_argument` in the `USING` clause or `RETURNING INTO` clause (or both) or with a define variable in the `INTO` clause.

Therefore, if you have a placeholder, you **MUST** have a `USING` (or `INTO` or `RETURNING INTO`) clause in the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement.

A [placeholder expression has the syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Placeholder-Expressions.html#GUID-B98B5394-A573-4BF8-9EC3-7B1BB1130553):

> #### placeholder_expression::=
>
> [image: placeholder expression syntax]

The `&` syntax is used for referencing [SQL/Plus substitution variables](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/using-substitution-variables-sqlplus.html#GUID-0BEEC1D7-876B-495C-9327-17037652D3D2).

> A substitution variable is preceded by one or two ampersands (&). When SQL*Plus encounters a substitution variable in a command, SQL*Plus executes the command as though it contained the value of the substitution variable, rather than the variable itself.

Thus substitution variable are typically processed by the client application and are never seen by the SQL engine (as the substitution variable will have been replaced by the value they are substituting for).

There is no obvious reason why `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` supports the use of substitution variable placeholder expressions; it appears to be an undocumented feature as the syntax does not support its use. However, it does work in the same manner as a bind variable placeholder expression.

---

If you bind the variable with the `USING` clause:

```sql
DECLARE
  sql_query varchar2(100) := '2*4 + &c';
  i number;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select ' || sql_query || ' from dual' INTO i USING 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
END;
/
```

Then the query works and the output is: `9`.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2ba47449b1c5162ddf81da523532d2f4)*

Comment: so I can't get value dynamically at the same time like this query "select 2*4 + &c from dual;" ??

Comment: @MTO wow, the PL/SQL compiler does indeed treat `&c` as a bind variable. I assumed it would be invalid because bind variables are normally prefixed with `:`, but now that I check I couldn't see anything in the PL/SQL manual explicitly specifying the prefix character, just a lot of examples using `:`

Comment: It seem that `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select &c from dual' INTO i USING 1` indeen *works* @WilliamRobertson, but I'd call it an **undocumented feature** until `MT0`provides the documentation link (BTW `&&c` fails with `ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name`). Anyway I'd prefere to use `:c` feeling the world will be safer...

Comment: @HryEsf The `EXECUTE IMMEDATE` documentation mandates that there must be a `USING`, `INTO` or `RETURNING INTO` clause if there is a placeholder expression in the dynamic SQL statement. As Marmite Bomber said, that it works at all appears to be an undocumented feature as it does not appear to be valid in the documented syntax (especially as substitution variable are handled during pre-processing in the client application and not during query execution in the database).